# new domain name while retaining the web hosting

Tags: domain-name-system, domain-name, 301-redirect

I have client/customer level rights to a 3 yr. old domain + windows web hosting (IIS web server) for http://www.22shrutiharmonium.com and it has html and asp pages.

Now, I need to change the domain name to www.22shruti.com (this has been purchased from another provider), but I want to keep the files on the currrent hosting (http://www.22shrutiharmonium.com). So, only domain name to be changed, not the hosting service.

Please guide me about the step by step procedure to -
1> Carry out the domain transition.
2> While retaining (OR, minimize the decrease in) the search engine credentials of my website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised this didn't get any sort of answer sooner.  The exact process will vary depending on the web server, but the general process would be:

1. Set up the new domain in DNS to direct to the IP of your web server.
2. Add an entry to the web server to serve requests on the new domain name, either as its own entry or as a virtual host on the existing entry for the website.
3. Once the new domain is verified working, update any hard-coded links in the website or application to use the new domain name.
4. Configure the web server or application to issue HTTP 301 Location header redirects when the old domain is used to redirect it to the new domain.  The 301 status code means "permanently moved" and the search engines will retain most pagerank for the entries and simply swap out the domains in their index.

Comment: Probably because it's a better fit for http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Contact hosting provider.
2. Discuss with them.
3. Do what they tell you.

Sorry, this is hosting provider specific. No clue why you even think asking here.